# Setting timezone with application using OpenNETCF.WindowsCE

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, opennetcf, windows-mobile-6.1

I'm developing an app for Windows Mobile 6.1 using the [OpenNETCF Smart Device Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx), and I am trying to update the time zone of the Windows Mobile device from my application using the [`SetTimeZoneInformation`](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/31857626-24a5-3acf-dec1-5fbdc2ba0c5b.htm) call.

The timezone I'm trying to set it to is GMT-5 Eastern (New York time zone, which observes daylight saving time), but the system is selecting to GMT-5 Bogota, Lima (which does not observe daylight saving time).

To confirm if I am setting it correctly, after setting the time zone, I called [`GetTimeZoneInformation`](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/faaf9f81-f061-625c-7d55-f3099d9386bf.htm) to see if the timezone what I set earlier is matching and it does. So, I don't know how this setting is getting messed up internally.

I found a similar question here, but there is no concise answer and there is a referenced link that is dead.

Here is some of the code I'm using:

```
var tzc = new TimeZoneCollection();
tzc.Initialize();

var currentTz = new TimeZoneInformation();
DateTimeHelper.GetTimeZoneInformation(ref currentTz);

var tziList = tzc.Cast<TimeZoneInformation>().ToList();
var configTzi = tziList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.StandardName == "Eastern Standard Time");

if (configTzi != null)
    if (currentTz.StandardName != configTzi.StandardName)
        DateTimeHelper.SetTimeZoneInformation(configTzi);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you link to the similar question you found please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine, but you said that New York time zone observes daylight saving time, so you may want to enable the Auto DST, which I could set by setting a key in the registry with that code :

```
const string key = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Clock";
Registry.SetValue(key, "AutoDST", 1);
```

Hope this helps, Best regards

Didier